# How to Disable Keyboard Keys Using Angular 2+. But, The keys should be work on HTML input fields

Tags: typescript, keyboard, input-field

Is there any way to disable the keyboard keys using Angular 2+(Typescript).
I want to disable all keys in keyboard. But, the keys should be work on HTML input fields.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Import this HostListener

```
 import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
```

Then, put this code to prevent keyboard keys..

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {

  console.log(event);
   event.returnValue = false;
   event.preventDefault();

   //or
   //do something

}
```

Comment: where does this code go?

Comment: @New-Way Inside your .ts file

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better formatted version to those that may have gotten confused from Sakkeer's correct answer

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
...
export class YourComponent{
    
 @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
 }
 ngOnInit() {}
}
```