# How to set default value for ngModel

Tags: angular

I want to make my input a default value as a small validate for user. But I can't seem to make it work since ngModel make it goes blank all the time.

```
<p class="mgRight">Second: <input type="number" min="1" [(ngModel)]="secondOnce" [(ng-init)]="secondOnce='1'" /></p>
```

Comment: define `model` in `component` and pass default value. eg: `@Input() secondOnce : number = 1 ` here is full documentations https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Comment: Thank you, it's work. Is there a way for me to prevent people from typing into it? Like you can edit it by cliking the arrow up-down but can't press anything.

Comment: here is solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230964/how-to-disable-keyboard-keys-using-angular-2-but-the-keys-should-be-work-on-h

Comment: Why are you using the hangfire tag?

Comment: @tomredfern oh I'm sorry. Will fix it right now.

Comment: Thank you. Also if you have a solution to the question then please post it as an answer. That way others can benefit.